# Как исправить или убрать ошибки вида "Declaration of ... should be compatible with", появившиеся с переходом на PHP 7

Tags: php7

С переходом на PHP 7 лог ошибок по многим старым проектам оказался забит под завязку сообщениями подобного вида:

```
PHP Warning: Declaration of Example::do(Foo $a, Bar $b, $c = 0) should 
  be compatible with ExampleParent::do($c = null) in Example.php on line 22548
```

Это только один пример ошибки. Вариантов таких ошибок может быть множество.

Усложняют проблему следующие моменты:

- Код проекта - бесконечный. Покрытие тестами - нулевое. Отрефакторить и исправить все ошибки займет приличное время. Никто не оплатит эту работу. Короче, исправлять *все* эти ошибки за исключением совсем уж простых - не вариант.
- Можно было бы вообще отключить все предупреждения, но тогда есть риск пропустить какие-то действительно важные ошибки. Отключать предупреждения совсем - не вариант.
- Не хотелось бы терять все те улучшения в части скорости и стабильности, которые есть в PHP 7. [Поддержка PHP 5 уже считай что закончилась](http://php.net/supported-versions.php), значит переходить на PHP 7 так или иначе будет нужно. Возвращаться на PHP 5 - не вариант.

С учётом вышесказанного, как можно освободить логи сервера только от этих ошибок?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если не [засовывать голову в песок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/682738/201364), что есть сил стараясь не трогать старый код, которые пока еще работает, то есть ряд случаев когда исправления могут быть внесены либо просто, либо выполнимо. В примерах ниже класс `B` является подклассом для `A`. Примеры ниже не обязательно устранят принципиальные нарушения [принципа подстановки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2) (LSP), но хотя бы PHP не будет о них ругаться.

1. Особой простой случай когда у метода подкласса есть новый аргумент, у которого нет умолчального значения. Просто добавляете значение по умолчанию и живете дальше. Пример:

   ```
   Declaration of B::foo() should be compatible with A::foo($bar = null)
   ```

   Вы сделаете:

   ```
   - public function foo()
   + public function foo($bar = null)
   ```
2. Если в методе подкласса добавляются ограничения, то следует убрать их из сигнатуры метода, перенеся в тело функции.

   ```
   Declaration of B::add(Baz $baz) should be compatible with A::add($n)
   ```

   Вы захотите использовать `assert` или кидать исключение, в зависимости от серьезности ошибки.

   ```
   - public function add(Baz $baz)
   + public function add($baz)
     {
   +     assert($baz instanceof Baz);
   ```

   Если вы видите что ограничения в сигнатуре метода используются лишь в целях документации, то перенесите их туда, где документируются параметры метода, то есть в комментарий.

   ```
   - protected function setValue(Baz $baz)
   + /**
   +  * @param Baz $baz
   +  */
   + protected function setValue($baz)
     {
   +     /** @var $baz Baz */
   ```
3. Если в методе подкласса меньше аргументов, чем в суперклассе, и вы можете сделать аргументы опциональными в суперклассе, достаточно будет заменить неиспользуемые аргументы заглушками.

   ```
   Declaration of B::foo($param = '') should be compatible with A::foo($x = 40, $y = '')
   ```

   Вы сделаете:

   ```
   - public function foo($param = '')
   + public function foo($param = '', $_ = null)
   ```
4. Если вы видите что какие-то аргументы в подкласс стали обязательными, уберите требование обязательности из сигнатуры метода в тело метода.

   ```
   - protected function foo($bar)
   + protected function foo($bar = null)
     {
   +     if (empty($bar['key'])) {
   +         throw new Exception("Invalid argument");
   +     }
   ```
5. Иногда может быть проще изменить метод суперкласса, удалив опциональный аргументы, перейдя на использование магии `func_get_args`. Не забудьте задокументировать этот виртуальный аргумент.

   ```
     /**
   +  * @param callable $bar
      */
   - public function getFoo($bar = false)
   + public function getFoo()
     {
   +     if (func_num_args() && $bar = func_get_arg(0)) {
   +         // go on with $bar
   ```

   Понятно что убрать больше чем один аргумент таким образом может быть сложно.
6. Все гораздо интересней если у вас есть серьезные нарушения принципа Лисковой. Если ваши аргументы не требуют типа, все просто. Достаточно сделать все аргументы опциональными, затем вручную проверяя их наличие. С такой ошибкой:

   ```
   Declaration of B::save($key, $value) should be compatible with A::save($foo = NULL)
   ```

   Вы сделаете:

   ```
   - public function save($key, $value)
   + public function save($key = null, $value = null)
     {
   +     if (func_num_args() < 2) {
   +         throw new Exception("Required argument missing");
   +     }
   ```

   Обратите внимание что мы не можем использовать функцию `func_get_args()` в этом случае потому что эта функция не учитывает аргументы со значениями по умолчанию. Их просто не будет в возвращенном значении.
7. Если у вас есть целые семейства классов с сильно отличным интерфейсом, может иметь смысл изменить их еще больше. Переименуем функцию, нарушающую принцип подстановки. Потом добавьте метод-прокси для вызова нового, переименованного, метода в едином для всей иерархии отклоняющихся классов подклассе.

   ```
   function save($arg = null) // соответствует родителю
   {
       $args = func_get_args();
       return $this->saveExtra(...$args); // отличный интерфейс
   }
   ```

   Таким образом вы не устраните нарушение принципа подстановки (новые классы все также нельзя вызывать будто они старые), но вы сохраните всевозможные проверки на типы данных, которые есть в сигнатурах функций.

Answer (score 4):

Такие ошибки как были предусмотрены [с PHP 5.0](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.0/Zend/zend_compile.c#L1860) и самого появления type hinting в PHP так и остались.

Единственное что сначала уровень `E_STRICT` не входил в `E_ALL` и должен был быть указан явно, затем начиная с PHP 5.4 начал входить. После этого в PHP 7.0 ошибки из `E_STRICT` [перераспределили по другим типам ошибок](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/reclassify_e_strict). Сообщество сошлось на мнении, что нарушение контракта базового класса - вещь плохая и должна быть заметна, потому присвоили этой ошибке уровень `E_WARNING`. Жаль, конечно, что [в 2004 году изменили](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/63e263f32a04b37d605ca48897a428fd10737244) изначальную реализацию этой проверки, где такой тип ошибок генерировал вовсе `E_COMPILE_ERROR`.

Ну кто же виноват, что ни вы ни ваши коллеги по проекту за столько лет ни разу не послушали, что говорит ближайший друг разработчика - компилятор вашего языка программирования.

Что делать дальше:

- исправлять. Рефакторить такие грубые ошибки будет долго и это говорит об общем качестве кода. Наверняка даже `E_NOTICE` не включали.
- игнорировать ошибки в логе
- прятать голову в песок и прятать ошибки

Настроек "такие варнинги выводи, а такие нет" - к счастью нет.

---

Конкретную описанную в вопросе ошибку можно перенести в рантайм. В базовом классе указан один параметр без типа с дефолтным значением, дочерний класс может принимать дополнительные необязательные аргументы метода и это не является нарушением контракта класса.

```
class ExampleParent 
{
    public function dosome ($c = null) {}
}
class Example extends ExampleParent 
{
    /*
     * переименовываем существующий метод
     * в будущем коде используем его вместо dosome
     */
    public function readablenamemethod(Foo $a, Bar $b, $c = 0) 
    {
    }
    /**
     * на его место ставим заглушку и вручную проверяем аргументы на совместимость 
     * @deprecated
     */
    public function dosome ($a = null, $b = null, $c = null) 
    {
        if ($a instanceof Foo and $b instanceof Bar) {
            // на такой набор параметров мы хотим реагировать
            return $this->readablenamemethod($a, $b, $c ?? 0);
        }
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('wrong arguments given');
    }
}
```

Если же базовый класс требует какой-то класс аргументом, а дочерний в этом месте хочет скаляр или совсем другой объект - то меняйте контракт базового класса с type hinting на проверку в рантайме.

Comment: Вопрос только про исправление. Если уберете первую часть до полосы, то ответ будет иметь шанс быть принятым. С первой частью ответ не на вопрос. Ответ должен быть исчерпывающим: пока рассмотрен только один вариант исправления таких ошибок. Я сходу могу придумать пять или семь.

Comment: Указать, что переход на PHP7 ничего существенно не изменил и ударить по рукам за говнокод (может быть не вас, но других читающих) - первая и основная часть ответа. Как жить дальше и проводить инкрементный рефакторинг - вторая. Как прятать голову в песок - не является решением проблемы. Можете придумать ещё способы - ну так опишите их в своём ответе.

Comment: Звонки недовольных клиентов в воскресенье вечером всё меняют. Если у вас нет никакой другой жизни кроме как в написании программ, то да, *для вас* этот ответ подойдет. Какая разница кто где что писал и у кого какие руки откуда?

Comment: @sanmai а с фига ли клиенты интересуются варнингами в логах?

Comment: Клиентам нет дела до логов, но вот если вы сайт удалением "говнокода" или неудачным рефакторингом сломали, то тут для них всё сразу меняется.

Answer (score 3):

Не всегда возможно исправить старый код, который вы, к тому же, не писали. Например, берёте какую-нибудь библиотеку из PEAR и наслаждаетесь. Про код, не знавший тестов, просто молчу. Потому можно сделать так:

```
if (PHP_MAJOR_VERSION >= 7) {
    set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr) {
       return strpos($errstr, 'Declaration of') === 0;
    }, E_WARNING);
}
```

Этот обработчик ошибок помечает предупреждения как обработанные, возвращая истину для всех сообщений, начинающихся с указанной строки. Такие обработанные преду­преж­де­ния не пойдут на запись в лог. Код будет работать только в PHP 7 и более поздних.

Если же проблема возникает только в какой-то части кода, которую можно выделить по ката­логу или путям до файлов, то можно глушить эти ошибки только для определённых файлов:

```
set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr, $file) {
    return strpos($file, 'path/to/legacy/library') !== false &&
        strpos($errstr, 'Declaration of') === 0;
}, E_WARNING);
```